# Passing values between modules

Tags: javascript, module, callback, return, browserify

I'm creating a question generator for a maths quiz, where the sum of a calculation is used in the following question. So far I've got the generator (mostly) working, however I'm struggling to pass the return values from **exportAll.return** to another module.

I'm still relatively new to js, so trying to get my head around fundamentals.

Here's what i've written to return results from the **numGen** generator (console.logs all work correctly):

```
var exportAll = exportAll || {}

exportAll.init = function(difficulty){
    numGen.init(difficulty)   //initiate numGen with random value
}

exportAll.update = function(start){
    numGen.updateNumber(start)   //update numGen with last answer
}

exportAll.return = function(start, partner, array){
    console.log('start number: ' + start) 
    console.log('question: ' + start + ' + '+ partner)
    console.log('correct answer: ' + (start + partner).toString())
    console.log(array)
}


module.exports = exportAll;
```

And I'm trying to pass the values (start, partner, array) in **exportAll.return** to this module:

```
var exportAll = require('../models/number_gen.js');

exportAll.init('easy'); 

module.exports = [

    {
        "question" : "What is ((START)) + ((PARTNER?))",

        "answer" : [
            (((ARRAY ITEM 1)),
            ((ARRAY ITEM 2)),
            ((ARRAY ITEM 3)),
            ((START + PARTNER))
        ],

        "correct" : (((START + PARTNER)))
    }

]
```

I've been reading about asynchronous callbacks and that I can't **return** a value, but I still don't fully understand the concept.

Thank you for any help!

### EDIT:

Here's the code for numGen:

```
var numGen = {

    init: function(difficulty){

        var initialMax, initialMin, difficulty

        if (difficulty == 'easy'){
            initialMax = 9
            initialMin = 1
        } else if (difficulty == 'medium'){
            initialMax = 99
            initialMin = 10
        } else if (difficulty == 'hard'){
            initialMax = 999
            initialMin = 100
        }

        var start = Math.floor(Math.random() * initialMax - initialMin) + (initialMin + 1)
        this.getlength(start, difficulty)
    },

    updateNumber: function(firstRand){
        var start = firstRand; 
        this.getlength(start)
    },

    getlength: function(start, difficulty){

        var startString = start.toString().length, maxAmount, minAmount

        if (startString == 1){
            maxAmount = 9
            minAmount = 1
        } else if (startString == 2){
            maxAmount = 99
            minAmount = 10
        } else if (startString == 3){
            maxAmount = 999
            minAmount = 100
        } else if (startString == 4){
            maxAmount = 9999
            minAmount = 1000
        } else if (startString == 5){
            maxAmount = 99999
            minAmount = 10000
        } else if (startString == 6){
            maxAmount = 999999
            minAmount = 100000
        } else if (startString == 7){
            maxAmount = 9999999
            minAmount = 1000000
        } else if (startString == 8){
            maxAmount = 99999999
            minAmount = 10000000
        }

        this.getPartner(maxAmount, minAmount, start, difficulty)
    },

    getPartner: function(max, min, start, difficulty){
        var partner = Math.floor(Math.random() * max - min) + (min + 1)
        this.getAnswer(start, partner, difficulty)
    },

    getAnswer: function(start, partner, difficulty){
        var answer = start + partner
        this.splitAnswer(start, partner, answer, difficulty)
    },

    splitAnswer: function(start, partner, answer, difficulty){

        var answerContain = [], 
            answerLength = answer.length

        if (difficulty == 'easy'){
            maxLengthLimit = 3
            minLengthlimit = 1
        } else if (difficulty == 'medium'){
            maxLengthLimit = 33
            minLengthlimit = 11
        } 

        var scramble1 = answer - (answer.toString().length * Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLengthLimit - minLengthlimit))
        var scramble2 = answer + (answer.toString().length + Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLengthLimit - minLengthlimit))
        var scramble3 = answer - (answer.toString().length - Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLengthLimit - minLengthlimit))

        answerContain.push(scramble1, scramble2, scramble3, answer)

        exportAll.return(start, partner, answerContain)

    }

}
```

Comment: So you are still wanting a way to access the values of `exportAll.return`?

Comment: Apologies for not replying, I figured it out! I assigned each value to a global variable then used an asynchronous callback to access from another module. I exported with `exportAll.init = function(difficulty, callback){
 numGen.init(difficulty)
  
 question = currentQuestion
 answer = currentAnswer
 choices = currentChoices

 callback(question, answer, choices)
}` 

and then called back using

 `numberGen.init('easy', function(question, answer, choices){
      currentQuestion = question
      currentAnswer   = answer
      currentChoices  = choices
    })`

Comment: That works, but be careful with globals :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is legit but code a little bit abstract. I'm going to give it a go anyway. You say you're having trouble returning values from the `exportAll.return` method. However, I'm not seeing where you ever actually `return` the values.

```
exportAll.return = function(start, partner, array){
        console.log('start number: ' + start);
        console.log('question: ' + start + ' + '+ partner);
        console.log('correct answer: ' + (start + partner).toString());
        console.log(array);

        //something like this
        this.start = start;
        this.partner = partner;
        this.array = array;

        return this; 
    }
```

Hopefully this gets you on the right track. However, if you can clarify a little further, I might can help some more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've removed any attempt of returning, as I didn't know the best way/couldn't get to work. I've updated my question with numGen

Comment: `return` just physically sets the result of the function. So you could do something like this: `var myResult = exporAll.return(startValue, partnerValue, arrayValue);` and then access each parameter value like so: `myResult.start`.

Comment: BTW there are lot's of different ways to use the value later ie `myResult.start`. I always use dot notation myself.